# Как привязать выполнение метода в расширенном объекте к выполнению метода в родительском объекте в extjs?

Tags: extjs

Допустим есть компонент:

```
Ext.define('Person', 
{
    initComponent : function(){
    },

    getPerson : function(){
        console.log('get Person');
    }
});
```

И его расширение:

```
Ext.define('Student', 
{
    extend : 'Person',

    initComponent : function(){

        //call parent class constructor
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getStudent: function(){
        console.log('get Student')
    }
});
```

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы после выполнения метода `getPerson`, всегда выполнялся метод `getStudent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать переопределить `getPerson`. Например, так:

```
Ext.define('Student',
{
    extend : 'Person',

    initComponent : function(){

        //call parent class constructor
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    getPerson: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.getStudent();
    },

    getStudent: function(){
        console.log('get Student')
    }
});
```

Пример на Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2m9i